# Check if value is between threshold limits for a defined time window - KQL query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, sliding-window, kusto-explorer

I want to write a query in Kusto which checks if the speed of a car is ALWAYS between a certain speed limit (e.g. b/w 100 and 150 km/h) for a window of 5 mins. Any leads shall be highly appreciated.

The following dataset can be used as an example:

| Timestamp | Speed | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:01:00.0000000 | 142.5 | 25.5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:02:00.0000000 | 133.2 | 25.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:03:00.0000000 | 124.8 | 25.6 |
| 2022-01-01 00:04:00.0000000 | 115.3 | 25.5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:05:00.0000000 | 98.4 | 25.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:06:00.0000000 | 106.3 | 26.3 |
| 2022-01-01 00:07:00.0000000 | 119.6 | 26.5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:08:00.0000000 | 134.7 | 25.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:09:00.0000000 | 128.2 | 26.6 |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:00.0000000 | 137.5 | 25.5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:11:00.0000000 | 139.9 | 27.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:12:00.0000000 | 140.1 | 26.3 |
| 2022-01-01 00:13:00.0000000 | 145.4 | 25.7 |
| 2022-01-01 00:14:00.0000000 | 158.7 | 24.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:15:00.0000000 | 155.8 | 25.6 |

The desired result would be as follows:

| Timestamp | Speed | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:06:00.0000000 | 106.3 | 26.3 |
| 2022-01-01 00:07:00.0000000 | 119.6 | 26.5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:08:00.0000000 | 134.7 | 25.4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:09:00.0000000 | 128.2 | 26.6 |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:00.0000000 | 137.5 | 25.5 |

The first and last 5 mins of the data are filtered out because in those 5 min windows the speed was found to be out of the 100 - 150 km/h range.

Comment: (1) Which 5 minutes? Last 5 minutes of the data? Last 5 minutes relatively to the execution time? Every interval of 5 minutes? (2) Which temperature? Average? Minimum? Maximum? (3) and if the condition is not fulfilled?

Comment: P.S. Please avoid the use of images for code and data samples

Comment: (1) Every 5 mins interval
(2) Temperature from the temperature column - not avg. or max.
(3) If condition is not fulfilled then do nothing

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense. Please give a larger data sample also add the desired results.

Comment: I have edited my question now and have also added the desired output. I hope it provides more clarity.

Comment: Could you share what you're trying to achieve? What Is your endgame here?

Comment: I need to check if the speed is always within a range for a certain time interval (5 mins in this case). If yes, then I would just plot the temperature data of that time interval.

The plotting part is no problem but first I need to get the relevant rows (as explained in the question) and that is what I don't know how to do with KQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let t = datatable (Timestamp:datetime ,Speed:real ,Temperature:real)
[
     '2022-01-01 00:01:00.0000000' ,142.5 ,25.5
    ,'2022-01-01 00:02:00.0000000' ,133.2 ,25.4
    ,'2022-01-01 00:03:00.0000000' ,124.8 ,25.6
    ,'2022-01-01 00:04:00.0000000' ,115.3 ,25.5
    ,'2022-01-01 00:05:00.0000000' ,98.4  ,25.4
    ,'2022-01-01 00:06:00.0000000' ,106.3 ,26.3
    ,'2022-01-01 00:07:00.0000000' ,119.6 ,26.5
    ,'2022-01-01 00:08:00.0000000' ,134.7 ,25.4
    ,'2022-01-01 00:09:00.0000000' ,128.2 ,26.6
    ,'2022-01-01 00:10:00.0000000' ,137.5 ,25.5
    ,'2022-01-01 00:11:00.0000000' ,139.9 ,27.4
    ,'2022-01-01 00:12:00.0000000' ,140.1 ,26.3
    ,'2022-01-01 00:13:00.0000000' ,145.4 ,25.7
    ,'2022-01-01 00:14:00.0000000' ,158.7 ,24.4
    ,'2022-01-01 00:15:00.0000000' ,155.8 ,25.6
];
let min_Timestamp = toscalar(t | summarize min(Timestamp));
t
| summarize make_list(Timestamp), make_list(Speed), make_list(Temperature) by bin_at(Timestamp, 5m, min_Timestamp)
| extend list_Speed_stat = series_stats_dynamic(list_Speed)  
| where list_Speed_stat["min"] >= 100 and list_Speed_stat["max"] <= 150
| mv-expand Timestamp = list_Timestamp, Speed = list_Speed, Temperature  = list_Temperature  
| project todatetime(Timestamp), toreal(Speed), toreal(Temperature)
```

| Timestamp | Speed | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01T00:06:00Z | 106.3 | 26.3 |
| 2022-01-01T00:07:00Z | 119.6 | 26.5 |
| 2022-01-01T00:08:00Z | 134.7 | 25.4 |
| 2022-01-01T00:09:00Z | 128.2 | 26.6 |
| 2022-01-01T00:10:00Z | 137.5 | 25.5 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WU3W6cMBCFr8NTjHKTRXIsG2x%20Nk1fIrmLIuTdHam0eBeB026iPHwGt9kYFwAhefhmOD5ju0MHDu7hYBzduw5h89haHJ2x/ZaC6GgE7KFHPGwHNB2wR7Q9Dsa9DOgjafKUXMFNJrLsVkh6QIitkFshuPh73QCTKuMaWKa5Tq5YDGcRnOc887BagPMIzhSvPFwswCqCpeb5qgw9h%20uKK1iVUUSVReEr03sBLmMZNS88vCSjit1QvFyVUcduVN66YskNKeLK5XpTZNzBvOY1weWSDBl3UAku19yQcQcVTc3LKBfguIO68m6oRRk6hvVlbTzfJR0tdtsem8sKp4XvTuPedGbYOHiH8cVaM7RvOGFfGyFN7xKXzD6bX9h07egCiAVRv19mkWDXpLB7hR3pMEE6A23ZXF1Kv8Szw%20MBphKNL9rQp2nDjji0OPrR2Bxej8a2%2080XlgJQ9p8fOGCc/HRNf7l%20hu/3IIUA8395IsyZiG9EaEF17O9bPPcTGVrns4IJ%20AKfcT9gEEwbLilhjKr3w%20kn7ukcOn0eODNX3Wk6ZS6W/huGfn4AafJCMsUEAAA=)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped in this case. 

However, is there a way to define sliding windows/bins in KQL?
For example, this sliding window would check if speed is in range from 1-5 mins, then 2-6 mins, then 3-7 mins, then 4-8 mins, then 5-9 mins ..... until 11-15 mins.

Comment: You're welcome. At this point, since you got an answer for your question, approve the answer and open a new post for the new question. You should give some thought to the expected result set.